# AJAX with Cordova and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I do not understand why this script works.
AJAX request on two different servers should not work...

AJAX in Cordova:

```
function getInfoBoat()
{
         $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.mywebservices.com/data-boat.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'html',
            cache:false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                $("#result").text(data)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
}
$("#get-info-boat").click(function()
{
        getData(); 
});
```

HTML POLICY:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not present on the PHP page

Grazie, ciao

RESPONSE HEADERS:
[image]

Comment: if target server has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` then results get returned..

Answer (score 0):

=== EDIT ===

CSP policy defines what 'limitation' or access client has,, and client can make AJAX reqs for sure,, but also, very important,, YOUR original server that renders the page need to have some custom CSP headers to prevent page to make ajax REQ!

See this page for info,, I tested this on my personal page moments ago, and now ajax REQ can't go to remote resources anymore :)

This is the link for you:

https://content-security-policy.com/

I have added something like this:

```
add_header "Content-Security-Policy" "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'";
```

and that's it!

cheers, k

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it well.
My domain is NOT present header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
AJAX should report an error but the script will work the same

Comment: can you see or paste us your headers from target server?

Comment: For now there is nothing, but only an echo 'test' to check that AJAX works

Comment: I have updated my anser take a look,, you have to open url from your server, then open Console -> Network -> Filter by Doc -> Header..

Comment: so your cordova app can access data from here: `http://www.mywebservices.com/data-boat.php` ? with that headers that shouldn't be possible

Comment: The AJAX request works either with access-control-allow-origin or without. That's what I do not understand. i test the my app on android device

Comment: that's right,, I tested that also,, what jquery version you have,, maybe that can be a factor here..

Comment: the version is 3.2.1.  Maybe it can be helpful if I try to print $ _SERVER ['HTTP_ORIGIN'] the result is FILE: //

Comment: you are working with a file, local machine,, I don't think that changes anythink .. I tested with jQuery ver; 3 & 1 and they both pull data :| I guess you'll have to put custom validation

Comment: I agree with you. Can you recommend me documentation to be able to validate that the request comes from Cordova APP? Thank you!